# How to get a .bin program on the STM32F4 discovery board?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32, flash

Simple question. I want to program this board: http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419

On my computer I've generated a .bin file using this library: https://github.com/emusan/stm32f4-template

How do I get said .bin file on the MCU program flash memory? What wires do I need? New to this process. For background, I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Page 4 of http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00037368.pdf

Comment: Do you mean section 4, page 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, use free CoFlash, it will do the trick. STM Discovery F4 has everything you need on board, all you have to add is USB cable.